# Highlight certain choices in a combo box

Tags: .net, user-interface

I've got a dropdown box with some items in it that are more popular than others, and I'd like those to have a different background colour (say, `Color.Yellow`) when the combobox is expanded. I see `BackColor` but is there a way to apply background colour to just a single item?

EDIT: Thanks to Astander's lead, here's how I solved it:

```
    Dim item = CType(e.Item, ImageComboBoxItem)
    If item.Value.Popular Then
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[ComboBox.DrawItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the lead! I've outlined what I did in the question, but I consider your answer "the answer" :)